# How do I change the default timeout setting in node.js in MarkLogic Grove?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-dhf, marklogic-10

I'm developing a UI application using MarkLogic Grove (React).

I'm calling the REST API from the UI, but it times out in 2 minutes.

I want to change this timeout of 2 minutes, how can I change it on Grove?

I changed the timeout to 10 minutes in the source below and restarted, but the timeout occurred in 2 minutes.

middle-tier/grove-node-server/node-server.js

```
---------------------------------
…
    server.timeout = 600*1000;

    return server;
  };
  return provide;
})();
```

Comment: Is there an error message that you can provide? This is the node HTTP request timing out, not the MarkLogic appserver execution timout, correct?

Comment: There may be multiple layers in play. If you run Grove using npm run start, it launches a webpack process in dev mode which might be timing out as well. And there might be transparent proxies in between, if you are hosting the code somewhere.